# Algorithm to generate a certain matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I am looking for a convenient way to generate a matrix of the following symmetric form (numbers could also run from -3 to +3 or just from -1 to +1):

[image]

Tips, anybody?

Comment: `Array[{{-2, -1}, {-2, -1}} + {#1 - 1, #2 - 1} &, {4, 4}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way:

```
n = 2;
Table[{{i, i + 1}, {j, j + 1}}, {i, -n, n - 1}, {j, -n, n - 1}]
```

or another

```
n = 5
Partition[Tuples[Partition[Range[-n, n], 2, 1], 2], 2 n] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your second solution is exactly what I needed. Would you accept my acceptance?

Comment: @eldo Thank :) I will glady accept it :P

Answer (score 3):

```
n = 2;
Table[{{-n, -n + 1} + i, {-n, -n + 1} + j}, {i, 0, 2 n - 1}, {j, 0, 
  2 n - 1}]
```

Comment: thanks, very nice, but it doesn't hold (in my case) for n>2. Try it with n=5 and compare with Kuba's answer.

Comment: @eldo I have changed it. I think it is working now fro any n.

Comment: yes, now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Table[{{-2, -1}, {-2, -1}} +
   i*{{1, 1}, {0, 0}} +
   j*{{0, 0}, {1, 1}},
  {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}] //
 MatrixForm
```

[image]